# How to solve a differential equation after integration.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The question is: Find the general solution of the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=2y+y^{3}$$

I have integrated by partial fractions to get to the following result:
$$\frac{1}{2}ln(y)-\frac{1}{4}ln(y^{2}+2)=x+C_{1}$$

I now need to solve it for y. I have put this question into an online calculator so I know the answer is:
$$y=-\frac{{{i\sqrt{2}}
e^{{\frac{1}{2}}(C_{1}+4x)}}}{\sqrt{((e^{C_1+4x})-1)}}$$ 
and 
$$y=\frac{{{i\sqrt{2}}
e^{{\frac{1}{2}}(C_{1}+4x)}}}{\sqrt{((e^{C_1+4x})-1)}}$$

I don't understand how to solve $$\frac{1}{2}ln(y)-\frac{1}{4}ln(y^{2}+2)=x+C_{1}$$ to get those answers... I tried using the quadratic formula and could only get it partially so I am either doing something accidentally wrong, or the quadratic formula is the wrong approach. If anyone could show me the steps of how to solve this it would be wonderful, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: One error I see right off: I assume you integrated at this point in your calculations?

$$\int \frac{dy}{y} + \int \frac{dy}{y^2 + 2}$$

That latter integral was not calculated properly. You assumed that you having a polynomial in the denominator just meant "plop that into the natural log" when that is generally only done for functions of the form

$$\int \frac{1}{x} dx$$

i.e. a first-degree equation in the denominator. You'll want to note in this problem, for a constant $c$:

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2 + c^2}dx = \frac{1}{c} tan^{-1} \left( \frac{x}{c} \right)$$

Comment: As a further, possibly anecdotal, thing: I'm assuming you're new to differential equations? In that case it might not be best to rely on on online calculators and such too much. For example, Wolfram Alpha gives this other form for that last antiderivative I mentioned. Both are valid but guess which one you might be intended to deal with given the relative simplicity:

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2 + a^2}dx = \frac{i}{2a} \left( ln\left( 1 - \frac{ix}{a} \right) - ln \left( 1 + \frac{ix}{a} \right) \right)$$

Source: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=antiderivative+dx%2F(x%5E2+%2B+a%5E2)

Comment: @EeveeTrainer : How do you detect that error? $$\frac1{y(y^2+2)}=\frac{y(2+y^2-y^2)}{2y^2(y^2+2)}=\frac1{2y}-\frac{y}{2(y^2+2)}$$ has exactly the integrals as provided.

Comment: By being dumb and doing math late at night. -_- My bad, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Okay so I didnt do the inegral wrong?

Comment: Yeah, you didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply with $4$, exponentiate, combine the sign with the constant to get
$$
\frac{y^2}{2+y^2}=Ce^{4x},~~~ C=\pm e^{4C_1}=\frac{y_0^2}{2+y_0^2}
$$
where the initial condition $y(0)=y_0$ was inserted. This you now can solve for $y^2$ and then discuss the square root.
$$
y^2=\frac{2Ce^{4x}}{1-Ce^{4x}}=\frac{2y_0^2e^{4x}}{2+y_0^2(1-e^{4x})}\\~\\
y(x)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2C}{e^{-4x}-C}}~~\text{ or }~~y(x)=\frac{y_0e^{2x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac12y_0^2(1-e^{4x})}}.
$$
In the second form the sign is already fixed to the sign of the solution. As $y=0$ is a solution, no other solution can have a change signs.

---

Alternatively, you can solve this as Bernoulli equation,
$$
(y^{-2})'=-2y^{-3}y'=-4y^{-2}-2\implies 2y(x)^{-2}+1=(2y_0^{-2}+1)e^{-4x}
$$

Comment: Is what you have found in the first part for y(x) the same as the answer provided by the online calculator? It looks different?
As for the Bernoulli equation, how does that give me what y equals?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. I do not know why WA insists on introducing complex numbers, even when the task is extended to include an initial condition, "y'(x)=2*y(x)+y(x)^3, y(0)=a", which works on other ODE to give a more sensible result. In the Bernoulli equation (set $u=y^{-2}$ if it was too fast) you can easily isolate $y(x)$, it gives the same result as above.

Comment: I was just wondering, when the square root is taken, what happens to the 2 in the numerator? Is it taken to be the power of e? Wouldnt that make it $e^{8x}$

Comment: Oh, there is a 2 in the numerator and denominator, im assuming they cancel.

Comment: Yes, they were canceled, that's why there is then a factor $1/2$. On the sympy online calculator https://live.sympy.org/ the command "`dsolve(Derivative(f(x),x) - 2*f(x)-f(x)**3, f(x))`" gives a better result.

Comment: Could you explain where the 1 came from in the denominator?

Comment: Your equation has the form $$\frac{a}{2+a}=b\implies a=2b+ba,~a(1-b)=2b,~a=\frac{2b}{1-b}.$$ I do not understand the next comment, the square root was lost, the terms do not correspond to a cancellation of $2$.

Comment: Is the answer still one positive and one negative due to the square root?

Comment: In principle yes, but in the form with $y_0$ in the denominator, the sign is already fixed to the sign of the solution. As $y=0$ is a solution, no other solution can change sign.

Comment: Is that still a general solution or a particular solution? Sorry if thats obvious im not familiar with ODEs

Comment: The equation is not linear, there is no homogeneous or particular solution. In this form it is the solution for $y(0)=y_0$.

Comment: Okay but the question wants a general solution, so is this still acceptable?

Comment: The second form is probably not general enough, it gives all solutions that cross the $y$ axis, but not all solutions have $x=0$ in their maximal domain. The first form is general.

Comment: The first form as in $$y(x)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2C}{e^{-4x}-C}}$$ ?

Comment: and does C still equal $$\pm{e^{4C_1}}$$

Comment: Yes, and $C$ can be any constant, $C=0$ gives the zero solution.

Comment: I think i get it, I don't really understand where that first form comes from though because to me it just looks like a lot of parts just disappear and i dont know how that happens.
Im so sorry for all the questions :/

Answer (score 1):

Writing the LHS as $ln(y^\frac{1}{2})-ln(y^2+2)^{\frac{1}{4}}=ln\bigg(\frac{y^\frac{1}{2}}{(y^2+2)^\frac{1}{4}}\bigg)$ then taking exponential we have

$\frac{y^\frac{1}{2}}{(y^2+2)^\frac{1}{4}}= e^{x+C_1}$ Removing the powers we have

$\frac{y^2}{y^2+2}=e^{4x+C_1}$ (Note I conveniently rewrote $4C_1$ as simply $C_1$ here.

I believe you can take it from here.

Comment: Could you keep going? I do not know how to proceed to end up with square roots and a fraction like it should be?

Comment: @Kayla Transpose the denominator and rearrange like you do for linear equations in one variable to get  $y^2= \frac{2\cdot e^{4x+C_1}}{1+e^{4x+C_1}}$. Then take the square root.